# how to have the background-color of a div red?

Tags: html, css

I have these divs with same classes and same css design containing pictures

```
<div class="it2" style="background: url(../images/ian.png) no-repeat top center;"></div>

<div class="it2" style="background: url(../images/top.png) no-repeat top center;"></div>

<div class="it2" style="background: url(../images/ylle.png) no-repeat top center;"></div>
```

what i was trying to do is when I hover on one of the divs the background will become red without covering the picture

any possible idea?

I tried adding in the css:

```
.it2:hover { background-color:red;}
```

but it is not working

Comment: How's `hacground-color` going to help? and I *think* what you're talking about is a semi-transparent red overlay? "Red without covering the picture"?

Comment: .it2:hover { background-color:red;}

Comment: @meagar I'm sorry its a typo ... I mean about "the red w/o cove" is that the picture will not be red but the background will be red.

Comment: @KevinBowersox tried that did not work

Comment: Remove the inline styling and move it to .it2 {
    background: url(../images/ian.png) no-repeat top center;
} and .it2:hover { background-color:red;} it will work

Comment: That still makes no sense. How can you see the background if there's a picture in the way?

Comment: @meagar I think you misunderstood me, what i was trying to do is add background color(red) to my picture when hovered. I'm sorry my english is bad.. but it is done now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming the typo in your code snippit is just in the posting, and not in the actual code?

Presuming that your actual css file has 'background-color' instead of 'hacground-color' as the property name, is all your CSS inline, or is some in a separate stylesheet? Inline CSS will always over-rule the stylesheet (which is one of the adcvantages of starting with everything in the stylesheet -- more room to work with, when changes need to happen.

Does your png have transparency and are you using a browser that supports that? If not, the background color will be behind the image, and thus you won't see the change.

If your site needs to work on browsers that don't render transparency properly, you may need to use two background images, (the only difference being the background color of the image) and use the CSS to switch between them.

Comment: Thanks I just realized that, silly me. I think I'll just change the whole code and use <img src> instead thank you ma'am

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.it2:hover
{
    background:url() no-repeat top center;
    background-color:red;
}
```